# MPMoviePlayerViewController, what if it fails?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, ios4, barcode-scanner

I'm creating an application to scan barcodes and provide video information on the scanned product. I'm running into the problem where the MPMoviePlayerViewController ends up giving me a white screen if a video url is not valid. It should just go back to the previous screen if no video is available. How do I handle this exception? I can't find any delegate methods etc..

Thanks in advance,

Lewion

Answer (score 0):

You can register yourself for a few notifications for `MPMoviePlayer` controller which is `moviePlayer` property of `MPMoviePlayerViewController` , these notifications should handle these error situations.

`PlaybackDidFinish` or `PreloadDidFinish` and couple of new ones with SDK 4.0+ , like `StateChanged` ... these come with `userinfo` dicitonary object from which you can detect error(s).